# How to set value checked in md-checkbox from typescript (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, typescript

i want to set value checked md-checkbox from typescript, this is my html code :

```
<a *ngIf="!menuItem.children">
<md-checkbox
[name]="name"
[checked]="(_checkingList(menuItem,selectedItems))"
[indeterminate]="(_checkIsIndeterminate(menuItem,selectedItems))"
(change)="_onChange(menuItem,$event)"
[disabled]="isDisable">
    <span>{{ menuItem.title }} <a (click)="tes()">tes</a></span>
</md-checkbox>
</a>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typescript:

```
isChecked = true;

toggle(){
   this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
}
```

Html:

```
<md-checkbox [checked]="isChecked" (change)="toggle()">Check me!</md-checkbox>
```

Here is the working plnkr:

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hgSeCsPFsMC06lCVKjUz?p=preview)